# Laravel raw query to eloquent model

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, raw

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sub_task_information st
WHERE
    created_at = (
        SELECT MAX(created_at) 
       FROM sub_task_information st2 
       WHERE st2.sub_task_id = st.sub_task_id 
             AND st2.user_id = st.user_id
    )
```

Need help to convert this raw query into eloquent model SubTaskInfo?

Comment: your question lacks research effort, show what you have done so far, read [how to ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why you need subquery? Seems like you can use query builder and ```orderByDesc('created_at')->groupBy(user_id)->limit(1)```

Comment: I'm not sure but try this:
`SubTaskInformation::join('sub_task_informations AS st2', function($query) {
        $query->on('st2.sub_task_id', '=', 'sub_task_informations.sub_task_id');
        $query->where('sub_task_informations.created_at', '=', \DB::raw('MAX(st2.created_at')));
    })->groupBy('sub_task_informations.id');`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test queries with the `tinker` shell without even hitting your database. Just use `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` to return the query.

[image: Tinker session]

This query has two tricky parts: The filtering by a subquery and the column comparison.

The first is not really documented at the moment, but the `where` method covers that use case if you use it like this: `->where(column, Closure)`.

For the second part, you need to use the `->whereColumn` method like this `->where(column1, column2)`.

```php
// Using plain Query Builder
$data = DB::table('sub_task_information', 'st')
    ->where('created_at', function ($query) {
        return $query->selectRaw('max(created_at)')
                     ->from('sub_task_information', 'st2')
                     ->whereColumn('st2.sub_task_id', 'st.sub_task_id')
                     ->whereColumn('st2.user_id', 'st.user_id');
    })
    ->get();
```

This is just using the Query Builder. If you want to use Eloquent, you'll need a model that is mapped to the `sub_task_informations` table.

If you have a model, for example `App\Models\SubTaskInformation`, you can still do the same query.

Instead of just replace `DB::table('sub_task_information', 'st')...` with `SubTaskInformation::from('sub_task_information', 'st')`

Usually you don't need the `from` method but in this query, you want to add an alias to your table in the outer select.

```php
// Using an Eloquent model while aliasing the table.
$data = SubTaskInformation::from('sub_task_information', 'st')
    ->where('created_at', function ($query) {
        return $query->selectRaw('max(created_at)')
                     ->from('sub_task_information', 'st2')
                     ->whereColumn('st2.sub_task_id', 'st.sub_task_id')
                     ->whereColumn('st2.user_id', 'st.user_id');
    })
    ->get();
```